# Default values for None but not 0

Tags: python

What is the idiomatic form for this:

```
foo = <something complicated>
if foo is None : foo = foo_default
```

I cannot use `foo = <something complicated> or foo_default` because then the 0 result of `<something complicated>` is replaced with `foo_default`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you currently have is idiomatic, there isn't a good way to put this logic into a single line.

Of course you can wrap this in a function if you are using this pattern often.

**Edit:** As a comparison between the other answers, consider the following two pieces of code:

- OP's current version:

  ```
  foo = <something complicated>
  if foo is None: foo = foo_default
  ```
- Answers suggesting a conditional expression:

  ```
  foo = <something complicated>
  foo = foo_default if foo is None else foo
  ```

To me using a conditional expression that might evaluate to `foo = foo` is less clear than using the one-line `if foo is None: foo = foo_default`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OP was asking about combining both the `foo = <something complicated>` line and the `if foo is None: foo = foo_default` line.  With the conditional expression you still need that first line that sets `foo`.

Comment: Ah, right, the problem is indeed perhaps that first `something complicated` must be assigned before you can test it.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`conditional expression`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions). (here in the form of a ternary operator)

```
>>> foo = bar if baz else qux
```

Or, using your data:

```
>>> foo = <something complicated>
>>> foo = foo_default if foo is None else foo
```

---

An example:

```
>>> foo = "A value"
>>> foo = foo if foo else "Nothing!"
>>> foo
'A value'
>>> foo = False
>>> foo = foo if foo else "Nothing!"
>>> foo
'Nothing!'
```

---

I would suggest though, because it seems that "something complicated" in this case means a function, that you simply have `foo_default` be returned in the function if it would otherwise return `None`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
foo = foo if foo is not None else foo_default
```

or inverted:

```
foo = foo_default if foo is None else foo
```

Like `or`, not all expressions are evaluated; in the form `true_expr if test_expr else false_expr`, either `true_expr` or `false_expr` is entirely ignored (not executed) depending on the outcome of `test_expr`.

This lets you test for specific pre-conditions before calling a method that doesn't exist, for example:

```
foo = foo(some, argument) if foo is not None else 'default value'
```

It does *not* let you test-and-assign without calling the complicated expression twice, no; you still have to use two statements, and there is no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use this also:

```
foo = (foo, foo_default)[foo==None]
```

Comment: The disadvantage here is that both `foo` and `foo_default` are evaluated before `foo==None` is checked.

Comment: I will *always* turn down proposed changes that include this idiom in a code review. It is hard to grok (you have to remember that `bool` is a subclass of `int`) and there are far more readable alternatives.